# Does GridSearchCV in sklearn train the model with whole data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I know that `GridSearchCV` will find the 'best' hyper-parameter by using k-fold cv. But after finding those hyper-parameters, will the `GridSearchCV` train the model again with the whole data set to get the trainable parameters? Or it only trains the model with the folds that generated the best hyper-parameters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to sklearn [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

lookup the keyword `refit` defaulted to be `True`.
I believe this answers your question.